# Is it good to store dynamically created file's paths in database ?

Tags: php

This is in reference with my earlier question [how to organize files created dynamically using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361723/how-to-organize-files-created-dynamically-using-php)

I edited the question , with one more aspect, that is storing paths in to the DB. Are there 
any advantages or disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Why not edit your original post rather than post a new one?

Comment: I tried doing it, but nobody answered then.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no other way of finding the file, storing its path in the DB is probably OK.

Still, a couple of notes :

- I would generally try to see if I could "guess" the file's path from another field -- for instance, from the primary key

  - If it's possible, then, there is no need to store the path in the DB, as it would be some redundant information
- I would, as much as possible, store some relative path, and not an absolute one.

  - For instance, I would store `images/my/image-test.png`
  - But not `/var/www/images/my/image-test.png`
  - That way, moving the directory with the images to another place, or changing of server, using a new one with another path to the DocumentRoot, would still be OK and not break my application.

Comment: True; if you can find the path using the ID it's useless to store it in the DB. What I do for example, is only store the file extension (for my image hosting section) and fetch `uploads/{$img->id}.{$img->ext}`.

Comment: I generally do kind of the same ;; I also often store the size *(in bytes)* and the content-type of the file : those two informations can be useful, when it comes to sending the file.